# Help with a supremum Norm proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, supremum-and-infimum

Let $C_o(R)$ denote the set of continuous functions on $R$ such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=0$. Prove that $C_o(R)$ is complete in the ||$\cdot$||$\infty$ norm.

I have know idea how to go about this...I think something to do with the limit of Cauchy sequences existing

Comment: Do you know that a uniform limit of continuous function is continuous?

Comment: Yes, I do know that

Comment: So if $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in this space, then $f_n$ converges uniformly to a function $f$, which is continuous. You only need to show that $\lim _{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$ for this function.

Comment: But arent we told that the limit of f(x)  as x $\rightarrow$ infinity for this?

Comment: You are told that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$. $f$ is the limit of $f_n$, which might not have this property.